# Custom select - get attribute name of selected dropdown

Tags: jquery, html

We need to get attribute name of selected dropdown for analytics. Now, if we click either one. it gets and display only "subject". "Country" attribute name is not getting.

```
<label>Subject</label>
<br />
<select name="subject" class="custom-select">
    <option value="">enquiry?</option>
    <option value="1">General enquiry</option>
    <option value="others">Others</option>
</select>

<label>Country</label>
<br />
<select name="Country" class="custom-select">
    <option value="Australia" selected="selected">Australia</option>
    <option value="2">New Zealand</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.custom-select').each(function() {
  var select = $(this).selectize({
    onChange: function(value) {
      Forms.onChangeSelectValue(value, select);
    },

    onBlur: function(){
      Analytics.pushData({
        eventCat: 'Form',
        eventAct: document.title,
        eventLab: $('select.custom-select').attr('name')
      });
    }
  });
});
```

"eventLab" is triggering only "subject". Not "country"

Not sure whether jQuery code used is wrong to call common element.

Comment: @Tushar - Missed out while copy/paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring a `var name` outside of the selectize() function call and then use it within. It should wire up the name attribute to the `onBlur` event:

```
$('.custom-select').each(function() {

  var name = $(this).attr('name');
  var select = $(this).selectize({

    onChange: function(value) {
      Forms.onChangeSelectValue(value, select);
    },

    onBlur: function(){
      Analytics.pushData({
        eventCat: 'Form',
        eventAct: document.title,
        eventLab: name
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It's still because of your jQuery selector. Try using `this` and see what happens.

Comment: Getting "undefined"... if i use $(this).attr('name');

Comment: See edit. I didn't see in my original answer that this was a function within a function within a function

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select.custom-select').change(function(){
$('#span').text($(this).attr('name'))


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Subject</label><br />
<select name="subject" class="custom-select">
  <option value="">enquiry?</option>
  <option value="1">General enquiry</option>
  <option value="others">Others</option>
</select>


<label>Country</label><br />
<select name="Country" class="custom-select">
  <option value="Australia" selected="selected">Australia</option>
  <option value="2">New Zealand</option>
</select>


<span id='span'></span>
```

Use `$(this).attr('name')`